# How can I make hash key lookup case-insensitive?

Tags: perl, hash

Evidently hash keys are compared in a case-sensitive manner.

```
$ perl -e '%hash = ( FOO => 1 ); printf "%s\n", ( exists $hash{foo} ) ? "Yes" : "No";'
No

$ perl -e '%hash = ( FOO => 1 ); printf "%s\n", ( exists $hash{FOO} ) ? "Yes" : "No";'
Yes
```

Is there a setting to change that for the current script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will have to use a tied hash. For example [Hash::Case::Preserve](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Hash-Case/lib/Hash/Case/Preserve.pod).

Comment: I wonder what the speed and space penalties there are for this implementation versus just making sure people get their hash keys in the right case in the first place?

Comment: I shouldn't cost much in space, though it will definitely cost in time. Having said that, in most cases it won't matter much IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

The hash of a string and the same string with the case changed are not equal.  So you can't do what you want, short of calling "uc" on every hash key before you create it AND before you use it.

Answer (score 5):

```
my %hash = (FOO => 1);
my $key = 'fOo'; # or 'foo' for that matter

my %lookup = map {(lc $_, $hash{$_})} keys %hash;
printf "%s\n", ( exists $hash{(lc $key)} ) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but when I run it in ActiveState Perl on Win32, I get "No".

I think you meant:

( exists $lookup{(lc $key)} ) ? "Yes" : "No"

Answer (score 1):

`grep` should do the trick if you make the pattern match case insensitive:

`perl -e '%hash = ( FOO => 1 );
 printf "%s\n", ( scalar(grep (/^foo$/i, keys %hash)) > 0) ? "Yes" : "No";'`

If you have more then one key with various spelling you may need to check if the match is greater than 1 as well.